# GNU assembler did not produce a program that I can execute

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86, gnu-assembler

I tried assembling some intermediate code generated by gcc.  I used the command `as -o hello hello.s`, which, as far as I can tell, is the correct syntax.  When I tried to run the program, it said `bash: ./hello: cannot execute binary file`.  It doesn't seem like there's a problem with the assembly code, since it was the code generated by gcc, and it doesn't seem like there's anything wrong with how I invoked the assembler, since that seems to be the right syntax according to [this manual](http://tigcc.ticalc.org/doc/gnuasm.html).  Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: `as` is an assembler, converting `.s` source files to `.o` object files. You still need to link them with `ld` to an executable file.

Comment: Okay, I didn't know I had to manually link the files.  I thought the assembler did that for you, just like a compiler.

Comment: Use the `file` command and you'll see it's a _relocatable_ (e.g. .o) even if you leave off the suffix.  What you want is an _executable_ which is what ld provides.  Since your .s/.o is from gcc, I'd suggest using gcc as the linker rather than ld because it may try to pull in things that gcc knows about but ld doesn't [at least without some cmdline options]--YMMV

Comment: A compiler also doesn't link, it just compiles. Run `gcc -v helloworld.c` on a tiny source file to see what programs gcc invokes to build an executable. Typically, there's 3 steps: compilation, assembly, and linking.

Comment: @Craig Estey: Yes, this is in fact what I did.  I was about to use ld, but I realized I would need to know where the library files for glibc are located, but gcc does all that for me.  It works.

Comment: Just a question: Say I assemble code using another assembler, like NASM.  Can I still link it using gcc, or should I use ld to link it?

Comment: @ZenHacker Wasn't sent to me, but I'll presume the NASM question was.  If it's _pure_ NASM, you may be able to use `ld`.  When you link to the gcc generated .s with ld, it also wants the "start" symbol `_start`.  With `ld` you would have to specify the "start" symbol (e.g. how does the ELF _loader_ [at runtime] know which address to transfer control to?).  You may be able to link in (e.g.) `crt1.o`--there are a few `crt*.o` variants.  They set up argc, argv, envp for main [which is hardwired inside `crt*.o`].

Comment: I did notice the link takes you to `tigcc` are you using tigcc and targeting TI calculators?

Comment: @ZenHacker : Here is a question you asked that had a couple of answers, but no answer was ever accepted. The question is, did any of the answers help? If there was one that did you may wish to accept one of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Working with GNU Assembler

Assume that your assembly file is called *hello.s* and looks something like (assuming a 32-Bit **Linux** target):

```
.data
msg:     .asciz "Hello World\n"
msglen = .-msg
.text
.global _start
_start:
    /* Use int $0x80/eax=4 to write to STDOUT */
    /* Output Hello World */
    mov $4, %eax       /* write system call */
    mov $0, %ebx       /* File descriptor 0 = STDOUT */
    mov $msg, %ecx     /* The message to output */
    mov $msglen, %edx  /* length of message */
    int $0x80          /* make the system call */

    /* Exit the program with int $0x80/eax=1 */
    mov $1, %eax       /* 1 = exit system call */
    mov $0, %ebx       /* value to exit with */
    int $0x80          /* make the system call */
```

This is a 32-bit Linux assembler program in AT&T syntax that displays `Hello World` to standard output using 32-bit system calls via `int $0x80`. It doesn't use any *C* functions so can be assembled with the GNU assembler `as` and linked with the GNU linker `ld` to produce a final executable.

```
as --32 hello.s -o hello.o
ld -melf_i386 hello.o -o hello
```

The first line assembles *hello.s* into a 32-bit *ELF* object called *hello.o* . *hello.o* is then linked to a 32-bit *ELF* executable called *hello* with the second command. The GNU linker assumes by default that your program starts execution at the label `_start` .

Alternatively you can use *GCC* to assemble and link this program with this command:

```
gcc -nostdlib -m32 hello.s -o hello
```

This will produce a 32-bit *ELF* executable called *hello* . The `-nostdlib` tells *GCC* not to link in the *C* runtime library and allows us to use `_start` as our program's entry point.

If your assembler program is intended to be linked to the *C* runtime and library so that it can utilize functions like *C*'s *printf* then things are a bit different. Assume you have this program that needs *printf* (or any of the *C* library functions):

```
.data
msg: .asciz "Hello World\n"
.text
.global main
main:
    push %ebp          /* Setup the stack frame */
    mov %esp, %ebp     /* Stack frames make GDB debugging easier */

    push  $msg         /* Message to print */
    call  printf
    add   $4,%esp      /* cleanup the stack */

    xor %eax, %eax     /* Return 0 when exiting */
    mov %ebp, %esp     /* destroy our stack frame */
    pop %ebp
    ret                /* Return to C runtime that called us
                          and allow it to do program termination */
```

Your entry point now must be `main`on most *nix type systems. The reason is that the C *runtime* will have an entry point called `_start` that does *C* runtime initialization and then makes a call to the function called `main` which we supply in our assembler code. To compile/assemble and link this we can use:

```
gcc -m32 hello.s -o hello
```

Note: on Windows the entry point called by the *C* runtime is `_WinMain`, not `main`.

## Working with NASM

In the comments you also asked about *NASM* so I'll provide some information when assembling with it. Assume that your assembly file is called *hello.asm* and looks something like (It doesn't require the *C* runtime libraries):

```
SECTION .data       ; data section
msg     db "Hello World", 13, 10
len     equ $-msg

SECTION .text       ; code section
    global _start     ; make label available to linker
_start:               ; standard  gcc  entry point

mov edx,len     ; length of string to print
mov ecx,msg     ; pointer to string
mov ebx,1       ; write to STDOUT (file descriptor 0)
mov eax,4       ; write command
int 0x80        ; interrupt 80 hex, call kernel

mov ebx,0       ; exit code, 0=normal
mov eax,1       ; exit command to kernel
int 0x80        ; interrupt 80 hex, call kernel
```

Then to build it into an executable you can use commands like these:

```
nasm -f elf32 hello.asm -o hello.o 
gcc -nostdlib -m32 hello.o -o hello
```

The first command assembles *hello.asm* to the *ELF* object file *hello.o* . The second line does the linking. `-nostdlib` excludes the *C* runtime from be linked in (functions like `_printf` etc wouldn't be available). The second line links *hello.o* to the executable *hello* .

Alternatively you can skip using *GCC* and use the linker directly like this:

```
nasm -f elf32 hello.asm -o hello.o 
ld -melf_i386 hello.o -o hello
```

If you need the *C* runtime and library for calling things like `printf` then it is a bit different. Assume you have this *NASM* code that needs `printf`:

```
    extern  printf

SECTION .data           ; Data section, initialized variables

    msg:      db   "Hello World", 13, 10, 0

SECTION .text           ; Code section.

    global main         ; the standard gcc entry point

main:                   ; the program label for the entry point
    push    ebp         ; Setup the stack frame
    mov     ebp, esp    ; Stack frames make GDB debugging easier

    push    msg         ; Message to print
    call    printf
    add     esp, 4      ; Cleanup the stack

    mov     eax, 0      ; Return value of 0
    mov     esp, ebp    ; Destroy our stack frame
    pop     ebp
endit:
    ret                 ; Return to C runtime that called us
                        ; and allow it to do program termination
```

Then to build it into an executable you can use commands like these:

```
nasm -f elf32 hello.asm -o hello.o
gcc -m32 hello.o -o hello
```

Comment: When gcc compiles main() (I mean C code), it may insert into it a call to some initialization routine. You don't have that in your assembly code, nor do you mention the conditions (if any), under which that extra call would be unnecessary to do, but a disassembled main() may show it to the surprise of the programmer and provoke questions.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze  No, what really happens is that when you compile in GCC's runtime library  `_start` is inside the _C_ runtime code. `_start` is where LD assumes by default code will start execution. When C runtime initialization finishes it then calls `main` as a _C_ function. I already covered that fact in my answer.That is why my code snippets use `main` when using GCC's _C_ runtime and `_start` when not using it. It is also why when using GCC's _C_ runtimes I set up the stackframes (which also aids with GDB debugging)

Comment: What really happens here (-c -S output on a main() calling puts("")):
`_main:
 pushl %ebp
 movl %esp, %ebp
 andl $-16, %esp
 subl $16, %esp
 call ___main ; <== see this???
 ...`

Comment: That isn't required to be called. Prior to hitting `main` the _C_ runtime is already set up. As for the `andl` that is required if you intend to use AVX instructions because you'll need 16 byte stack alignment for instructions that require specific alignment (also helps with SIMD performance)

Comment: If it's not required, why does the compiler do it? Not that compiler bugs are unheard of, but maybe there's a reason for the call here because the setup is somehow incomplete?

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze To give you a specific answer I would need to know what version of GCC you are using (or is it clang) to tell you what that specific compiler is doing. The `main` entry point is ultimately where user code will start. However it is possible for GCC and the C runtime to make calls prior to entering your actual main routine.

Comment: Nope. Mingw x86 gcc 4.8.2.

Comment: @Alexey: Aha, figured it was another environment. Give me a bit to look at the generated code. Also explains the extra underscore.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze On Win32 `___main` performs C++ initialization. If you aren't using C++ and just C code the call to `___main` effectively does nothing useful for _C_ code, so it can be entirely excluded. If you were targeting C++ (this user talked about gcc, not g++) then on some platforms you may have to do other setup and initialization.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze : I saw similar code generated with `gcc version 4.9.2 (Rev5, Built by MSYS2 project)`

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze : specifically `___main` does the initialization of static constructors for C++ objects. There is no such thing in standard _C_, so that code will not find any constructors to call and will return back effectively doing nothing.

Answer (score 3):

Neither a compiler nor an assembler generates an executable file. Both generate an *object file*, which can then be linked with other object and/or library files to generate an executable.

The command `gcc -c`, for example, invokes just the compiler; it can take a source file like `hello.c` as input and generate an object file like `hello.o` as output.

Likewise, `as` can take an assembly language source file like `hello.s` and generate an object file like `hello.o`.

The *linker* is a separate tool that generates executables from object files.

It just happens that compiling and linking in one step is so convenient that that's what the `gcc` command does by default; `gcc hello.c -o hello` invokes the compiler *and* the linker to generate an executable file.

Note that the `gcc` command isn't just a compiler.  It's a driver program that invokes the preprocessor, the compiler proper, the assembler, and/or the linker.  (The preprocessor and assembler, can be thought of as components of the compiler, and in some cases they aren't even separate programs, or a compiler can generate machine object code *instead of* assembly code.)

In fact, you can perform the same multi-step process in one command for assembly language as well:

```
gcc hello.s -o hello
```

will invoke the assembler and linker and generate an executable file.

This is specific to gcc (and probably to most other compilers for Unix-like systems).  Other implementations might be organized differently.

Comment: There are, of course, assemblers that emit executables without producing linkable object files as an intermediate step. It's just not the case here.