# NASM scanf undefined reference (LINUX)

Tags: linux, assembly, nasm

I am new with assembly. And I have problem with code. I am trying to create simple program using scanf.

This is code:

```
global main
extern printf
extern scanf

section .text

section .data
 message: db "The result is = %d", 10, 0
 request: db "Enter the number: ", 0
 integer1: times 4 db 0 ; 32-bits integer = 4 bytes
 formatin: db "%d", 0

main:
 ;  Ask for an integer
 push request
 call printf
 add esp, 4    ; remove the parameter

 push integer1 ; address of integer1, where the input is going to be stored
 push formatin ; arguments are right to left (first  parameter)
 call scanf
 add esp, 8    ; remove the parameters

 ; Move the value under the address integer1 to EAX
 mov eax, [integer1]

 ; Print out the content of eax register
 push rax
 push message
 call printf
 add esp, 8

 ;  Linux terminate the app
 MOV AL, 1
 MOV EBX, 0 
 INT 80h
```

i compile it with:

```
nasm -f elf64 -o program.o program.asm
```

and:

```
ld -o program program.o
```

but when i try ld i get error:

```
program.o: In function `main':
program.asm:(.data+0x34): undefined reference to `printf'
program.asm:(.data+0x46): undefined reference to `scanf'
program.asm:(.data+0x5b): undefined reference to `printf'
```

I am working on 64-bit linux.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Those functions come from libc. Use `gcc -o program program.o` to link. Also, do not use the exit syscall to terminate the program, rather just `ret` or `call exit`. Furthermore, that's a 32 bit program, so better use `-f elf32` and `gcc -m32`.

Comment: when i try with gcc i get thia error: i386 architecture of input file `program.o' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output and collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: As I said, use `gcc -m32`

Comment: Jester is correct. I wrote a [Stack Overflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33714801/3857942) that may help. In particular the very last example and the way you compile it with _NASM_ and _GCC_ (using the _C_ runtime) applies to your question. The example code also creates a proper stack frame and frees it at the end (aids in debugging with _GDB_), and uses `ret` to return from the program.

Comment: `push rax` is a 64-bit instruction. It should be `push eax` in your 32-bit code.

Comment: Although you are on a 64-bit OS, the code you have is 32-bit (if you change RAX to EAX in the code). Running 32-bit code on a 64-but Linux system isn't a problem as long as you assemble with _NASM_ using `-f elf32` instead of `-f elf64` and link with _GCC_ using `-m32`. This produces a 32-bit executable. Your 64-bit Linux will still be able to run the 32-bit code. From my other SO answer you'd be assembling and lining with `nasm -f elf32 -o program.o program.asm` and `gcc -m32 program.o -o program` which will generate an executable called _program_

Comment: re: what Michael said:  look up the ABI for x86-64 vs. the ABI for x86-32bit.  See the links at http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info.  Agner Fog's site has a doc about ABIs.

Answer (score 1):

You're not linking with any libraries with your ld command.  `scanf` and `printf` are defined in the C library, so you can link with that:

```
ld -o program program.o -lc
```

or you can use some other library that defines those functions, if you have it available.